# Staining newbie: how to match these stains that primarily color the grain?

Tags: staining

### Background

I'm building a computer standing desk. I bought a nice base from Autonomous.

I bought a teak 72" x 25" table top from Lowe's with a live edge.

This is my first ever wood-staining project.

I've watched plenty of videos, and am planning to sand, pre-condition, then stain with oil-based stain and apply oil-based poly finish.

### Here's my question:

I really love the idea of contrast in my stain.

I especially LOOVE these stains below that primarily affect the grain.

I bought a bunch of samples, and am considering mixing & matching.

Q: How can I replicate the center stain, bottom left, or bottom right stain? Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> I've watched plenty of videos, and am planning to sand, pre-condition, then stain with oil-based stain and apply oil-based poly finish.

You need to watch more videos. Or actually ditch that idea, you need to read some finishing books or good articles in the woodworking magazines.

There's nothing wrong with any of the steps you've mentioned here, or all of them in that sequence, except that step number two may or may not be called for depending on what you're working with. If the wood you're dealing with is indeed teak<sup>1</sup> *it's not called for*.

As any and all decent guides to staining, or specifically on the use of "pre-stain" or "conditioner", should have clearly informed the reader, these products basically have one job: to prevent blotching in blotch-prone woods<sup>2</sup>. *Teak is not one of them.*

> Q: How can I replicate the center stain, bottom left, or bottom right stain? Any advice?

You can't in two of the cases. What you're seeing in these boards is largely just the natural grain of the wood (but see note below).

These appear to be charcuterie/serving boards, so automatically one should assume they're not stained. The board front and centre for example, that's probably olive which is prized for those lovely wild/chaotic dark lines (one of the few species that has this). The board directly under it is a common softwood – wood from an evergreen conifer, possibly Douglas fir – but regardless of which species it is, the pronounced dark/light contrast in the each growth ring is a natural feature that is common to most softwoods.

I have no idea what's going on with the board in the top-left corner (reclaimed wood maybe??)! The only board here that for sure has been stained is the one bottom-right. That looks like it is another piece of common softwood that was simply slathered in "gel stain" in a dark colour.

**Note:** the grain contrast in these boards is high and we can see they don't look 'dry', as bare sanded wood usually does. So part of that is likely that it has been highlighted by the wood being oiled (with mineral oil most likely) which increases contrast, as all oils do to one degree or another. But also, as a marketing photo the image could have been enhanced in multiple ways<sup>3</sup> to make it look better — I'd actually be more surprised if it *wasn't* enhanced these days — so this might not even be that accurate a representation of the colour or contrast in these boards. It's impossible to tell for sure but I wouldn't be surprised if orange wasn't amped up a smidge, and the contrast increased slightly...... this is what I'd naturally do in Photoshop/GIMP if I wanted to make a photo of many woodworking projects 'look their best'.

---

<sup>1</sup> IF it is indeed teak, which I doubt given the availability of and cost of teak these days.

<sup>2</sup>  All you'll accomplish by using "conditioner" before staining a wood that doesn't need it is limit the amount of stain the wood is capable of absorbing, in other words you guarantee a lighter staining result, and possibly a less dramatic staining outcome (depending on the wood type and its grain type/structure).

<sup>3</sup> A single 'enhance' option in an app for example likely does more than one thing, including but not limited to some colour manipulation, a bump in the contrast and/or the application of a particular type of sharpening called Unsharp Mask.

Comment: Some days I wish I could give you 2 up votes

Comment: @bowlturner, thank you! I've wished the same thing when I read an Answer I thought was particularly good (and there are many, particularly back in the early days).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a wood with an open grain (oak, ash) you can try the following:

1. Sand and prepare as usual.
2. Clean the wood thoroughly using mineral spirits or denatured alcohol.
3. Apply a dark dye / dye stain.  Let it dry.
4. Sand the wood, with the goal of only leaving the dyed dark parts in the grain.
5. (Repeat 3-4 as desired).
6. Vacuum any sanding dust off.
7. Seal dye coat -- use a shellac based sealer.  This will allow you to put an oil finish over top and not worry about the dye 'running'.
8. Apply your next stain, as usual.
9. Top Coat as usual.

I did this a few years ago for an ash desktop:
[image]

I used:

- Lee Valley Aniline Dye
- Emtech Shellac Sealer
- General Finishes Carbon Grey Gel Stain
- General Finishes Gel Top Coat

I'm happy with the result, but between coats wasn't particular enough with the sanding (I had initially done a very careful, thorough job) but re-introduced some low grit scratches/pigtails.

Comment: An alternative approach you might like to try in future is do the background staining, if any, first, then apply some topcoat and after that comes the colouring agent for the recessed grain. This is basically the methodology for 'cerused' wood (AKA white liming) and it has the advantage that the grain colouring can be nearly anything, including wall paint or enamel/gloss, "gel stain" and even wax as in white liming, although I'm not a fan of that as it's not durable.

Comment: Thank you -- I wasn't aware of this process!  Will tuck it in my back pocket for a future desk/table.